# MVC 5 - authorisation blues with forms authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

With WebForms I don't have a problem with forms authentication, but it's giving me grief in MVC 5

Added `Secure` to Areas, then Landing and Login

[image: MVC areas]

In the main web.config file added this under system.web (also variants like `~/Secure/Login`)

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Secure/Login" />
</authentication>
```

And sub web.config file (under secure) this (sorry indent wouldn't work so used code snippet)

```html
<location path="">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Login">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>​
```

But for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: Microsoft's official response is that you cannot secure an MVC application via web.config.  You must Authorize attributes or other AuthenticationFilters.  http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/asp-net-mvc-authentication-global-authentication-and-allow-anonymous

Comment: I'm more concerned with finding a way to redirect to the login page - I can add <Authorize()> above the class in the controller(s) but I don't want users to hit a 401.0

Comment: If you remove the authorization sections from your config, and follow the advice in the article I referenced, you won't have a problem.

Comment: Erik - thanks for the link. The actual problem was Startup.Auth. Adding the path now sends <Authorize> to the login page. I notice (from your link) that I can configure <Authorize> from Account Controller - question - should this be done from the main one, or do I create another under the area for that area? Thank you for replying

Comment: You use AllowAnonymous attribute to override the Authorize attribute in global filters, which is documented in the article I linked

Comment: In the end I did away with forms authentication, this link helped a lot in the setup http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/asp-net-mvc-5-authentication-breakdown-part-deux - thank you for replying, it put me on the right track - my answer was part of the solution (LoginPath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this to Startup.Auth and it works perfectly

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions() With {.LoginPath = New PathString("/Secure/Login")})
```